# Worklight 6.1 - Calling a protected adapter procedure in init method

Tags: jquery, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a general design question that I would like get some feedback on.

- I have an application with 3 procedures, which all 3 require enduser
  security and are protected by a security test.
- In my application, I call 2 of the protected adapter procedures within my Worklihgt init method.
- When I fire the application up, I am presented with a login screen (by the challenge handler), because I have tried to access a protected procedure in the init method.
- I am seeing some strange (JQuery display) issues, but that's not my question.

The question is: Is the is a good design? Is there another way to throw up a login screen?

Thoughts????

Comment: Ya it is good when comes to protecting the procedures. But if you want to present the login screen beginning and from that authentication session ,If you want to protect the procedures. Then that can also be done by the security test for environment and same security test for the procedure .

Comment: If you are looking for any other way of authentication trigger you can use `WL.Client.login(realm, options)`. See the link for more information http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_login.html

Comment: Note that you should use the 6.1 IC and not 5.0.5.... http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. Appreciate your thoughts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to have the login screen show up immediately upon an init, and you are having this show up by triggering an adapter procedure, then this is not the best way to handle this. You can assign a security test to your application in your application-descriptor.xml file. That way, whenever your app tries to access any resource on the server (including an init) the challenge will be sent. You shouldn't have to invoke a protected procedure to trigger a challenge on init.

If init is the first thing that is called upon your app startup and it is calling an adapter that will pull up a login screen in response to a challenge, then why not show the login by default?

That all being said, I wouldn't go as far as to say that this is *bad* design, but I wouldn't do it this way myself.